# Read a checkbox from a View, from the controller, and dynamically insert a value into the database with mvc?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, checkbox

I have a rather complex schema for handling and mapping my web users with my company's internal and external employees. I have a subclass table all_employees that has two columns, `employee_id` and `employee_type`.

I need to find a method to enroll my employees as web users. I was thinking of using a checkbox inside the create/edit views for my employees. Then when we go to create a web user account, they'll simply select the appropriate user from the drop down box along with the company. It will then match it to the `all_employees` table, and I'll be able to easily identify everyone.

If there is a simpler method, I'm definitely open to suggestions, but for the time being, does anyone know of a good method of dynamically inserting a value into my `all_employees` table upon the value of a checkbox being true?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your schema and employee classes? I'm assuming the `employee-type` is "External" or "Internal" and that web user is a boolean property of `employee`.

Comment: I have updated my original post with my full employees schema, if it is too small, you can view a larger version here: http://i.imgur.com/x6KBBNo.png

Comment: The schema is more 'confusing' than it is 'complex. Are you able to change it or is it something you've inherited? I'm finding it hard to work out how the `employee`, `all` and `companies` relate to one another. You appear to have primary/foreign key relationships going both ways. To answer the original question I'd suggest checking the current state of the bit field and then just use an `if/else` in your controller logic to update the tables.

Comment: It's actually been modified. There is no longer a constraint on them, and the field can be nullable. So in `all`, if the type is 1, it pulls from `employee.employees`, if it is anything other than 1, it pulls from `companies.employees`. The way it is constructed, there can be a web user without being tied to an employee, and there can be employees without being tied to web users. The `all_id` remains present within the `employees` tables as a debug failsafe, to ensure everything is being purged properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise that you take another look at your schema and tidy it up.

To edit the `all_employees` table based on a boolean value I'd do something like this:

### ViewModel

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public bool all { get; set; }
    public string etc... { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.all)
        {
            do something;
        }
        else 
        {
            do something else;
        }
    }
```